# Can you always Invoke instead of checking InvokeRequired?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know you have to Invoke to do a cross thread update. But if Invoke isn't required can you call the code the same way you would if the Invoke were required?

So instead of this:

```
if(rtbSearchResults.InvokeRequired)
{
    var ctuDelegate = new SearchResultsCrossThreadUpdate(SetSearchResultsRTB);
    rtbSearchResults.Invoke(ctuDelegate, new object[] { resultString });
}
else
{
    SetSearchResultsRTB(resultString);
}
```

Can I just do this and accept a performance penalty?

```
var ctuDelegate = new SearchResultsCrossThreadUpdate(SetSearchResultsRTB);
rtbSearchResults.Invoke(ctuDelegate, new object[] { resultString });
```

Comment: Have you tried the code? what happens?

Comment: I'm asking about in general.

Comment: Why use such code in the first place? Use `async/await` instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Good luck using async/await in WinForms.

Comment: @IanKemp no problem at all. Been doing that since 2012. Problems occur for the same reason `Invoke()` can lead to deadlock - when you try to call `Invoke()` while the UI thread is already blocked by another operation, perhaps one waiting for that `Invoke()`. Invariably, it's due to unfortunate coding

Comment: @IanKemp besides, one should *never* try to update the UI directly from business code or worse, other threads. Data binding, or `IProgress` make separating the UI from the logic a *lot* easier

Answer (score 2):

One problematic situation is the case that you want to access controls on a form that doesn't yet have a handle. For example, if you call some initialization function on a created form to fill the form's controls before showing the form.

In this case, calling `Invoke` on the controls will throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

Consider this form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Action a = () => { textBox1.Text = "A"; };
        textBox1.Invoke(a);
    }
}
```

And this code calling the form

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Test();
form.ShowDialog();
```

This will result in an exception because the `Invoke` is called on the `TextBox` while it doesn't have a handle yet.

Include a check for `InvokeRequired` and there will not be an exception.

```
public void Test()
{
    Action a = () => { textBox1.Text = "A"; };

    if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBox1.Invoke(a);
    }
    else
    {
        a();
    }
}
```